# How to run these asynchronous functions in loop, sequentially?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Below written javascript code runs asynchronously and produces output in the following format.

```
const check = () => {
    const arr = [3,2,1]

    arr.forEach(async (val) => {
        await setTimeout(() => console.log(val), val*1000)
    })
}

check();
```

The actual output is:

```
1
2
3
```

But I want output in the following format:

```
3
2
1
```

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise so awaiting it doesn't work. Even if it did, `forEach` doesn't work for async functions. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Use an actual for loop instead of `forEach`

Comment: Do you want it to fully wait for one to finish printing before starting the timer on the next?

Comment: Do you really want to run `setTimeout()` or some other asynchronous function? The answer will be very different depending on weather the function you want to call return a promise or does not return a promise (like setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Recusrion might do the trick.

```js
const check = () => {
    const arr = [3,2,1]

    var i = 0, val;
    const do_the_thing = ()=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
        val = arr[i];
        i++;
        console.log(val);
        if(arr[i]) do_the_thing();
      }, val*1000)
    };

    do_the_thing();
}

check();
```